# Axiom of extensionality, an example with concrete sets.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Axiom of extensionality says: $\forall A\forall B\big(\forall X(X\in A\Leftrightarrow X\in B)\Rightarrow A=B\big)$ or in words:

Given any set $A$ and any set $B$, if for every set $X$, $X$ is a member of $A$ if and only if $X$ is a member of $B$, then $A$ is equal to $B$.

Let's say we have two sets:
$A=\big\{\{1\}\big\}\;$ and $\;B=\big\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\big\}\,.$

We are trying different combinations of: for every set $X$ (existing in the universe?).

1. $X=\{1\}$
   $\{1\}\in\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\text{true}$
   $\{1\}\in\big\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\big\}=\text{true}$
   $\big(\text{true}\Leftrightarrow\text{true}\big)=\text{true}$ **(OK)**
2. $X=\{3\}$
   $\{3\}\in\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\text{false}$
   $\{3\}\in\big\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\big\}=\text{false}$
   $\big(\text{false}\Leftrightarrow\text{false}\big)=\text{true}$ **(OK)**
3. $X=\{1,2\}$
   $\{1,2\}\in\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\text{false}$
   $\{1,2\}\in\big\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\big\}=\text{true}$
   $\big(\text{false}\Leftrightarrow\text{true}\big)=\text{false}$ **(violation)**

As we have found some set $\,X\,\big(\pmb{\{1,2\}}\big)$, which doesn't satisfy: $X(X\in A\Leftrightarrow X\in B)$ it means that $A$ and $B$ are not equal?
Have I understood the axiom correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have understood the axiom correctly, but you need to learn to write mathematical formulas, symbols and notations. So click in the link [Mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and read it carefully.

Comment: Thanks Angelo. I will read it and next time follow the MathJax conventions.